# CGAL rotation by x-axis in 3D

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

Is there a predefined rotation by the x-axis in CGAL. If not, why not? If I have to define it, how would I do it?

```
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Aff_transformation_3.h>
#include <cmath>
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Aff_transformation_3<Kernel> transform3D;

transform3D rotationX(double angle)
{
    const double cosa{cos(angle)};
    const double sina{sin(angle)};
    return transform3D(
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, cosa, -sina,
            0.0, sina, cosa);
}

void test()
{
    using Point3D = CGAL::Point_3<Kernel>;
    Point3D p{1.0,1.0,1.0};
    const transform3D rotate{rotationX(M_PI_2)};
    rotate(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To rotate in 3D one can use [Aff_transformation_3](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Aff__transformation__3.html) and specify the transformation matrix using a [transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations).

For example: To rotate on the x-axis for a certain angle x one can use a matrix like:

```
1   0        0         0
0   cos(x)   -sin(x)   0
0   sin(x)   cos(x)    0
0   0        0         1
```